# how could I solve "ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)"? ( A problem with cPickle in python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, load, pickle

I'm using python 3.x and I want to run below code:

```
import cPickle
x = cPickle.load(open('s01.dat', 'rb'))
```

It works very well in python 2.x but when I try in python 3 I get this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cPickle'

I solved it by some other post in the StackOverflow and changed my code to :

```
import _pickle as cPickle
x = cPickle.load(open('s07.dat', 'rb'))
```

And I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position
>   8: ordinal not in range(128)

I try to solve it by changing the encoding like:

```
import _pickle as cPickle
x = cPickle.load(open('s07.dat', 'rb',encoding='iso-8859-1'))
```

or

```
import _pickle as cPickle
x = cPickle.load(open('s07.dat', 'rb',encoding='utf-8'))
```

but still I get this error:

> ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

My *.dat file contains two arrays, and I expect to import them!
How could I overcome these problems?

Comment: @101arrowz yes I have tried this and I got >TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' error!

Comment: @101arrowz Actually, I want to load a dataset and I don't have enough information about this! some descriptions are available in this link: (https://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/mmv/datasets/deap/readme.html#prep)

Comment: The files are pickled python/numpy  formats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem is solved by using @Macattack 's answer as below:

```
import pickle 
x = pickle.load(open('s07.dat', 'rb'),  encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

Answer (score 2):

First, if you're trying to use `pickle` in python3, just do `import pickle` (it uses the compiled cPickle when available) or `from six.moves import cPickle` if you need compatibility with python2.

Second, the encoding option you need is the one that gets sent to `pickle.load` not to `open`. Try:

```
x = cPickle.load(open('s07.dat', 'rb'), encoding='utf-8')
```